# redirects to the php login page not accessible

Tags: php

Redirect to login page in php but can not access home.php when login successfully. Please help

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($email,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect('home.php');
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</html>
```

home.php

```
<?php
  include("checklogin.php");
  check_login();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php
function check_login()
{
if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
    {   
        $host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extra="index.php";     
        $_SESSION["login"]="";
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
    }
}
?>
```

before logging on to home.php will redirect to index.php.
When successful login, the error rate Too Many Redirects

Comment: You are using some PHP framework?

Comment: check_login() function is not required at all. Just including page is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `session_start();` for your home page code.  You are getting too many redirects error since session is not started on `home.php`

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include("checklogin.php");
  check_login();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)`  and see whether login variable is in the session.?

Comment: See when not logged in http://thuongton.cf/home.php and when login with email // pass: demo@demo.com // demo @ 123

Comment: seems you are using cookies in user class. isn't? better to add code of user class too to question

Comment: thank you i add code <?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()=="")
{
  $user_login->redirect('index.php');
}

?> and it good